# Arithmetic progressions inside non meager sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is non-meager Borel set, then $A$ contains arithmetic progressions of every finite length. I know that this is false if we do not assume that $A$ is Borel. In particular, there are non-meager $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ does not even contain arithmetic progressions of length 3. But how far can this be pushed?

More concretely, for a given $n \geq 3$, do the length-n arithmetic progression free non-meager sets live inside every non meager set?

Comment: I don't understand the wording of the question (last sentence). Free refers to (length-$n$ arithmetic progression)-free? "live" seems to be "is contained in", but with this try of decoding I'm not sure the question makes sense.

Comment: Large cardinals can push this straightforwardly beyond the Borel. Suppose $A$ is non-meager and has the property of Baire; then $A\cap U$ is comeager in $U$ for some open $U$, so for simplicity assume $A$ is genuinely comeager. Let $A^c=\bigcup F_i$ with $F_i$ nowhere dense, and note that $cl(F_i)$ is also nowhere dense; so $A$ contains the comeager $G_\delta$ set $(\bigcup cl(F_i))^c$, which clearly contains lots of finite arithmetic progressions. In particular, the statement is true in ZFC for analytic sets, and true for projective sets given a measurable above infinitely many Woodins.